# Setting updateStrategy = FieldStrategy.IGNORED has no effect

Tags: sql-update, mybatis

I add annotation on the field I need to update it to null.
@TableField(updateStrategy = FieldStrategy.IGNORED)

Mapper.updateById(order)

But It has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

try updateStrategy=FieldStrategy.NEVER